# Parameterised OFFSET FETCH NEXT query (EF Core) has 10x slower performance

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I'm running the following query through (generated by Entity Framework Core) Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio against a SQL Azure database table with ~46,000 rows which takes ~5seconds

```
DECLARE @__TypedProperty_0 as int = 20
DECLARE @__TypedProperty_1 as int = 20

SELECT [dto].[Id], [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Surname], [dto].[AzureId], [dto].[Email]
 FROM [Associates] AS [dto]
 ORDER BY [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Id]
 OFFSET @__TypedProperty_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__TypedProperty_1 ROWS ONLY
```

This results in the following execution plan:

[image: Parameterised query execution plan]

The same query, in-lining the parameters like below runs in 500ms - 10x faster!

```
SELECT [dto].[Id], [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Surname], [dto].[AzureId], [dto].[Email]
 FROM [Associates] AS [dto]
 ORDER BY [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Id]
 OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

But results in an almost identical execution plan:

[image: Inline parameters execution plan]

This code is generated by EntityFramework Core so I am not in control of it.  My questions are:

- why do these seemingly identical execution plans result in drastically different performance results
- how can I improve the performance of the parameterised version of this query?

---

*This table is created essentially like this (some columns omitted for brevity):*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Associates](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AzureId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Forename] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Associates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

---

Edit:

Parameterised plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.520" Build="15.0.300.379" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="3" StatementEstRows="100" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="130" StatementSubTreeCost="5.37918" StatementText="SELECT [dto].[Id], [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Surname], [dto].[AzureId], [dto].[Email]&#xD; FROM [Associates] AS [dto]&#xD; ORDER BY [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Id]&#xD; OFFSET @__TypedProperty_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__TypedProperty_1 ROWS ONLY" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x0DE3D0FE5886DC7C" QueryPlanHash="0xF19DA08DF72AADE7" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSqlHandle="0x09005281339FAE104036AAAECEB2DCBF22BA0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" DatabaseContextSettingsId="4" ParentObjectId="0" StatementParameterizationType="0" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="EstimatedDOPIsOne" MemoryGrant="242880" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="192">
            <Warnings>
              <MemoryGrantWarning GrantWarningKind="Excessive Grant" RequestedMemory="242880" GrantedMemory="242880" MaxUsedMemory="8824" />
            </Warnings>
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="512" SerialDesiredMemory="909960" RequiredMemory="512" DesiredMemory="909960" RequestedMemory="242880" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="242880" MaxUsedMemory="8824" MaxQueryMemory="242888" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="17616030" EstimatedPagesCached="1101001" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" MaxCompileMemory="849240" />
            <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="4860" WaitCount="63" />
              <Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="2622" WaitCount="190" />
            </WaitStats>
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="293" ElapsedTime="5152" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="1E-05" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5.37918">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="20" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="5151" ActualCPUms="292" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                <OffsetExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@__TypedProperty_0],0)">
                    <Identifier>
                      <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1002">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="@__TypedProperty_0" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </ColumnReference>
                    </Identifier>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </OffsetExpression>
                <TopExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@__TypedProperty_1],0)">
                    <Identifier>
                      <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1001">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="@__TypedProperty_1" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Convert>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </ColumnReference>
                    </Identifier>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </TopExpression>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="3.27909" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="100" LogicalOp="Sort" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5.37917">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="40" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="5151" ActualCPUms="292" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="242880" OutputMemoryGrant="242496" UsedMemoryGrant="8824" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Sort Distinct="false">
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="0.050878" EstimateIO="2.03794" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="46110" EstimatedRowsRead="46110" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.08882" TableCardinality="46110">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="46110" ActualRowsRead="46110" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="859" ActualCPUms="33" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="2759" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Index="[PK_Associates]" Alias="[dto]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Sort>
                </RelOp>
              </Top>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@__TypedProperty_0" ParameterDataType="int" ParameterRuntimeValue="(20)" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@__TypedProperty_1" ParameterDataType="int" ParameterRuntimeValue="(20)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Non parameterised plan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.520" Build="15.0.300.379" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="20" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="130" StatementSubTreeCost="5.37917" StatementText="SELECT [dto].[Id], [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Surname], [dto].[AzureId], [dto].[Email]&#xD; FROM [Associates] AS [dto]&#xD; ORDER BY [dto].[Forename], [dto].[Id]&#xD; OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x0DE3D0FE5886DC7C" QueryPlanHash="0x320ECFD7D3D25A6E" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSqlHandle="0x0900910E3823662F71FB79B11C319338FB890000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" DatabaseContextSettingsId="4" ParentObjectId="0" StatementParameterizationType="0" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" NonParallelPlanReason="EstimatedDOPIsOne" MemoryGrant="1024" CachedPlanSize="24" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="168">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="336" SerialDesiredMemory="352" RequiredMemory="336" DesiredMemory="352" RequestedMemory="1024" GrantWaitTime="0" GrantedMemory="1024" MaxUsedMemory="336" MaxQueryMemory="243624" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="17616030" EstimatedPagesCached="1101001" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" MaxCompileMemory="848432" />
            <WaitStats>
              <Wait WaitType="SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD" WaitTimeMs="1713" WaitCount="23" />
              <Wait WaitType="RESOURCE_GOVERNOR_IDLE" WaitTimeMs="1130" WaitCount="83" />
            </WaitStats>
            <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="96" ElapsedTime="1808" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="4E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="20" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5.37917">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="20" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="1808" ActualCPUms="95" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                <OffsetExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(20)">
                    <Const ConstValue="(20)" />
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </OffsetExpression>
                <TopExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(20)">
                    <Const ConstValue="(20)" />
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </TopExpression>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="3.27909" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="40" LogicalOp="TopN Sort" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5.37917">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="1" Output="1" />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="40" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="1808" ActualCPUms="95" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="0" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" InputMemoryGrant="1024" OutputMemoryGrant="1024" UsedMemoryGrant="336" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TopSort Distinct="false" Rows="40">
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="16117" EstimateCPU="0.050878" EstimateIO="2.03794" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="46110" EstimatedRowsRead="46110" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.08882" TableCardinality="46110">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="46110" ActualRowsRead="46110" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="1009" ActualCPUms="31" ActualScans="1" ActualLogicalReads="2759" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Id" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="AzureId" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Email" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Forename" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Alias="[dto]" Column="Surname" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[MomentaUAT]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Associates]" Index="[PK_Associates]" Alias="[dto]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </TopSort>
                </RelOp>
              </Top>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: They *look* identical, but *are* they identical? Take a closer look at the row estimates in each plan. Or better yet, [paste the plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). That exclamation mark in the final step is telling! It may well be warning you about spills.

Comment: As an aside, in general, it's all well and good that `OFFSET 20` can be made fast -- but are you always going to be passing `20`? Try `OFFSET 43000` and I think you'll see that hurts just as much with or without parameterization. You may be barking up the wrong tree if you merely focus on "get this as fast as that".

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have updated my question with the xml execution plans.

You actually make a very good point and when doing this what is interesting is that the inline parameter version takes longer - 6 seconds, but the parameterised version still takes 6 seconds

Comment: @HenryIng-Simmons:Can you try eliminating data type mismatches in EF generated code ` <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@__TypedProperty_1],0)">`

Comment: I would start with an index on the order by columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add an index  that supports the ORDER BY ([dto].[Forename], [dto].[Id])and that covers all of the columns in the SELECT clause.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Associates_Forename_ID  
ON Associates (Forename, Id)  
INCLUDE (Surname, AzureId, Email);
```

As you can see in the plan, doing pagination without proper index originates scans or key lookups and that is the reason behind poor performance.

Comment: Pagination is going to be scanning even with a fully covering index -- that's just the nature of the beast. An index does not store row offsets. (Also, putting columns you're already indexing on in the `INCLUDE` isn't legal, and if it was legal it'd be a waste of space regardless.) An index can still help in reducing I/O and eliminate sorting, of course, but it will not reduce pagination to seeking.

Comment: Also adding an index on all columns as you are suggesting seems a bit heavy handed for my particular problem.

Comment: @Jeroen https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: I don't see anything on that page which contradicts what I said. Although it's certainly true you can optimize pagination with a few more tricks -- but your answer isn't discussing those. (Fixing the error in your statement is easy, incidentally -- just remove `Id` and `Forename` from the `INCLUDE`.)

Comment: Please read the second paragraph again. There you will find the impact of indexes in pagination.

Comment: I didn't say there was *no impact*. I said that no index is going to reduce pagination to *seeking*. My contention is not that you're wrong when you say that adding an index could help -- my contention is that formulating this as "doing pagination without proper index originates scans" is misleading, as doing pagination *with* proper indexes will still involve scans! (You can clearly see this in every execution plan on that page -- perhaps you meant to say "table scans".)

Comment: Have a great day.

Comment: Thanks Alberto this has worked (with @JeroenMostert 's modification).

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen for removing the unneeded attributes on the included columns.